# Configure "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" on a remote project

Tags: c++, eclipse, remote-access, remote-server

I have *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers*, Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
I need to configure it to work on a virtual machine having a large C/C++ project.
I should have a remote access to it from Eclipse probably having SSH connection.
For that case I wanted to use Remote System Explorer , but installing it - got a message that it is not compatible with Eclipse version
What is correct solution to work remotely with eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I tried in my system. May be it will help you.

1.Download and install Java 1.8 and above.

2.Download and install Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers.

3.Open Eclipse.

4.Goto Window→Show View→ Other.

5.Search Remote and select 'Remote Systems'.

6.A window will get opened at the bottom. "Remote Systems"

7.Hover the mouse over that window and right click. Select 'New Connection'.

8.Select 'SSH Only' and click on 'Next'.

9.Put the details of the **Host Name:** and click on 'Finish'.

Comment: which IDE do you use? (I dont have  these tabs/bars)

Comment: Eclipse IDE for C++ Developers.

Comment: Eclipse IDE 2020-06 (4.18.0) Window-> Show View -> Others ..... does not contain "Remote Systems" or anything else that can be found by searching "remote".

Comment: this only launches an ssh shell, but how do you then import the project into eclipse?